# display 25 numbers arranged 5 by 5 order

Tags: c

I am having a problem arranging 25 numbers into 5 by 5 order. This is what I have so far:

```
int main() {
    int num,arr[100];
    int i, y, swap;

    num = 25;

    printf("Enter %d integers \n",num);

    for(i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
        printf("\nElement %d: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < ( num - 1 ); i++) {
        for(y = 0 ; y < num - i - 1; y++) {
            if(arr[y] > arr[y+1]) {
                swap     = arr[y];
                arr[y]   = arr[y+1];
                arr[y+1] = swap;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("Sorted list in ascending order:\n");
    for ( i = 0 ; i < num ; i++ )  
        printf("%d \t", arr[i]);

    getch();
}
```

I am expecting my output will be like this.

```
Sorted list in ascending order:
x x x x x
x x x x x
x x x x x
x x x x x
x x x x x
```

Comment: And what is it that is not working? What's your output? Have you debugged it to see where it's going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
...
   printf("Sorted list in ascending order:\n");
   for ( i = 0 ; i < 5; i++ )  {
       printf("%c%d", (i % 5) ? '\t' : '\n', arr[i]);
   } 
   printf("\n");   
...
```

Or, after "chux", without the leading newline:

```
...
   printf("Sorted list in ascending order:\n");
   for ( i = 0 ; i < num ; i++ )  {
       printf("%d%c", arr[i], ((i % 5) != (5-1)) ? '\t' : '\n');
   }   
...
```

And, if you want the columns nicely aligned, add an appropriate width to the `%d`:

```
printf("%10d ... ");              /* right aligned */
```

or

```
printf("%-10d ... ");             /* left aligned */
```

Comment: why u use %c for (i % 5)

Comment: This prints a `'\n'` before the first `"x x x x x"` and lacks a `'\n'` after the last `"x x x x x"`.

Comment: @COL the `(i % 5)` is part of a larger expression `(i % 5) ? '\t' : '\n'` which results in a tab or a newline character depending on the "truthiness" of `(i % 5)`

Comment: @chux Hence the additional `printf("\n");` line.  If the initial newline offends, there are more complicated schemes to accomplish the newline every 5th line.

Comment: Yes I missed the trailing `printf("\n");` So an up-vote on that.  I do think there are [ways](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35559231/2410359), not more complicated ways, to avoid the initial newline.

Answer (score 0):

Just one modification:

```
printf("Sorted list in ascending order:\n");
for ( i = 0 ; i < num ; i++ )  
{
  printf("%d \t", arr[i]);
  if(i % 5 == 0) putchar('\n');
}
```

Comment: you just add if(i %% 5 == 0) putchar('\n'); ? how it works

Comment: It works like this - `every 5 numbers (if i is divisible by 5 with 0 remainder), put a newline char to make a row.`

Comment: This will not work and illustrates the reason why using braces is good practice....

Answer (score 0):

Avoid printing extra space-tab after the last number.

To get visually lined up values, use a print width.

```
int print_width = 4;
int columns = 5;
for (i = 0 ; i < num ; i++ )  {
  printf("%*d", print_width, arr[i]);
  putchar(i%columns == columns-1 ? '\n' : '\t');
}
```